# Accidentally uninstalled product key of windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-activation

So someone trolled me and made me run "slmgr.vbs /upk" in command prompt. Now my product key is uninstalled. I just borrowed this laptop and the owner of this laptop doesn't know much about what is windows activating things. So i tried System restore, doesn't work. There's a product key below the laptop and I tried using that but it says "The product key you have entered will not work on this edition of windows 7". Is there anyway I can recover and restore the activation key?

Comment: You will have to ask the owner of the laptop what their license key is because it sounds like, they installed a different version of Windows 7 then the device came with.  You can also call the Microsoft Activation Center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a chance the key is also [in the Registry](https://www.howtogeek.com/245445/how-to-use-slmgr-to-change-remove-or-extend-your-windows-license/).

- Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and type `regedit`.
- Select `Regedit` and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> in the UAC dialog.
- Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Win7` (or copy that path into the Search bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
- Double-click on the Value `ProductKey`.

[image: Windows 7 Product Key in Registry]

You might also try a third-party tool such as free Nirsoft's [ProduKey](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html).

If all else fails, you can [buy the license](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-request-a-new-windows-product-key-2624936) from Microsoft. Or install another OS such as Linux, e.g.free [Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: @Ramhound, Nirsoft's products are *all* free, and  the purchase suggested is from Microsoft itself.

Comment: I seriously misread that sentence...

Comment: Thnx boi, i used ProduKey Cracked version. I even got 3 valid windows 7 ultimate product keys

Comment: @ShaunZyrille, There is no "cracked" version of Nirsoft's ProduKey, which is free anyway; whatever you used sounds a bit dodgy.